# How to reliably get the size of a markup label in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

If I don't use markup=True, then this works:

```
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
lbl = CoreLabel(text=text, font_size=font_size)
lbl.refresh()
size_needed = lbl.texture.size # Need this size to display the label
```

But as soon as I start using markup, it doesn't work. The main problem is that things like `[font=/path/to/font.ttf]Test[/font]` is interpreted as plain text (instead of a markup) and results in a width value that is much higher than it should be. I have also tried to use the markup version of CoreLabel:

```
from kivy.core.text.markup import MarkupLabel as CoreMarkupLabel
```

But for some reason, it also ignores the markup language and calculates the size as if it was plain text. For example, a simple font awesome icon that is about 20 pixels wide has `texture.size[0]=1218`. I have also tried to create a normal `kivy.uix.label.Label` but it always has `texture_size=(0,0)` until I actually add it to a window and render it. But **I do not want to actually display the label**. I just want to know the size needed for it.

Background: I need to create tooltips and dialogs that resize themselves to fit their contents. Most of the content will be markup text in a label, but sometimes there will be other small things added (a close button or an extra icon). For this, I need to determine the size occupied by the content **BEFORE** I display the content.

Comment: I guess I could write my own parser, split the markup text into parts with specific font sizes and font names, and then calculate and summarize the sizes for these parts. But that seems to be very very inefficient, especially from Python code.

Comment: I guess the size of your label is the same with or without markup, so you must calculate the size of your label without the markup tags and use this size to create your true label

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true. I'm using font awesome for embedding icons in the text. Also the font size can be changed in the middlemof the text with the [size=30] markup.